Plotly Limited WebGL instances when using subplots
I'm trying to produce a figure using Python and plotly, it's meant to consist of a considerably large number (>=25) of subplots, each of which is a 3D surface plot.
I am running into issues with my browser limiting the number of WebGL instances that can run at any point, it seems that each subplot initiates a new WebGL instance. According to this page I can use virtual WebGL to bypass this problem, however the post only shows how to use it in Jupyter Notebook, I am running a normal .py script in Pycharm.
The following example code demonstrates the problem.
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

N = 64
nx, ny = 5, 5

z = [0, 1, 2]
y = [0, 1, 2]
x = [0, 1, 2]

xy, yx = np.meshgrid(x, y)
xz, zx = np.meshgrid(x, z)
zy, yz = np.meshgrid(z, y)

zsurf = go.Surface(y=yx, x=xy, z=np.ones(xy.shape), showscale=False)
ysurf = go.Surface(x=xz, z=zx, y=np.ones(xz.shape), showscale=False)
xsurf = go.Surface(z=zy, y=yz, x=np.ones(zy.shape), showscale=False)

specs = np.tile(np.array({"type": "scene"}), [nx, ny]).tolist()

fig = make_subplots(nx, ny, specs=specs)

for ii in range(nx):
    for jj in range(ny):
        fig.add_trace(zsurf, row=ii+1, col=jj+1)
        fig.add_trace(ysurf, row=ii+1, col=jj+1)
        fig.add_trace(xsurf, row=ii+1, col=jj+1)

fig.show()

The output in my browser looks like this:
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/7FbvBTeK.png
With 9 instances of the following warning in my browser console:
"WARNING: Too many active WebGL contexts. Oldest context will be lost."
My question is how do I modify the above script to display all subplots? Either by incorporating Virtual WebGL, or through some other means?
Many Thanks
